# "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" due to filter using angularjs

Tags: javascript, filter, angularjs

Take a look at the following:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4571/musicopeTypescript/musicopeTypescript/index.html

when you type "a" in the input box, you obtain the `10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` error.

Do you have any idea, why that happens?

**EDIT:** Here is the code that makes problems:

http://embed.plnkr.co/PTkvPc

**EDIT:** It looks like it is a problem of Song.clone. If I replace it by angular.copy, then it works. Anybody could explain that?

Here is the working version:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8Jk1pR?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your filter modifying the original data somehow? That's the only specific thing that looks like it would cause the infinite digest cycle.

**EDIT**: in regards to different cloning functions lead to different behavior.

I suspect one is doing deep cloning, the other is not, and in one case AngularJS is checking object equality and your filter is creating new objects each time, causing the problem.

I'd suggest breaking up some of that logic and perhaps moving some of it into the controller or additional filters. The filter that narrows down your array should only be doing that, and just return references to the original objects. Then you can write other filters to manipulate the tags, etc.

Also +1 for Abba. :P

Comment: Well I try to avoid that by copying the old data to new data. It however seems that the Song.clone function is wrong. See my first post.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sounds as a reasonable suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: I found that my filter evolved from being a simple filter into a directive and it was causing this infinite loop.  Once I converted it to a directive it worked great!

Answer (score 4):

To understand why is this is happening, it's good to understand [how angular works runtime](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime). Basically there are watchers that keep returning back different values, and so it keeps going through the $digest loop and then stops it from infinitely looping. From their [$digest() documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest):

> Process all of the watchers of the current scope and its children. Because a watcher's listener can change the model, the $digest() keeps calling the watchers until no more listeners are firing. This means that it is possible to get into an infinite loop. This function will throw 'Maximum iteration limit exceeded.' if the number of iterations exceeds 10.

Without knowing what your code is doing, it's hard to give a specific solution to why this is happening in your case, but this should answer your questions as to when this error is thrown.

Comment: Yeah, you are right in that it is something about infinite recursion. I just don't know why it keeps calling again and again. I have prepared small plunker. See my first post.