# Advanced filtering with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking to filter the following list with AngularJS by both category and location. The difficulty I'm having is being able to properly nest the results beneath their respective categories (see below) after the filtering has occurred.

```
var jobs = [
    {
        title: "Software Engineer",
        category: "Engineering",
        location: "New York"
    },
    {
        title: "Web Developer",
        category: "Engineering",
        location: "Chicago"
    },
    {
        title: "UX Designer",
        category: "Design",
        location: "New York"
    }
]
```

This is the desired output (also note the alphabetically ordered categories):

**Design**

UX Designer

**Engineering**

Software Engineer

Web Developer

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19992090/2592994

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example with your data on plnkr using the filter solution from [AngularJS Group By Directive without External Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19992090/2592994):

http://plnkr.co/edit/w5UJUN?p=preview

Comment: Exactly, what I needed - thanks a million! Do you know if this will create any limitations with filtering the list?

Comment: No there are no limitations with filter. Updated the plnkr with applied filter "New York" on location.  `<div ng-repeat="job in jobs | orderBy:'category' | groupBy:'category' | filter:{location: 'New York'}">`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like this in your mind:

```
  <b>Design</b>
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter: { category:'Design'}">
        {{job.title}}
      </li>
  </ul>
  <b>Engineering</b>
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter: { category:'Engineering'}">
        {{job.title}}
      </li>
  </ul>
```

There is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qcp8d/).

Comment: I've, thought of something like this, but I don't want to need additional markup for every new category that gets added.

Comment: Then I would suggest making set of categories and iterate trough them with the use of `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

I would re-structure my JSON as follows:

```
  $scope.parsedJobs = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.jobs, function(value, key) {
    var j = $scope.parsedJobs.filter(function(element) {
      return element.category == value.category;
    });
    if (j.length > 0) {
      $scope.parsedJobs[0].elements.push({
        title: value.title, 
        location: value.location
      });
    } else {
      $scope.parsedJobs.push({
        category: value.category,
        elements: [{
          title: value.title, 
          location: value.location
        }]
      });
    }
  });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/meniguhu/1/edit?html,js,output)