# AngularJs Custom Limit Filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, group-by

My goal is to limit no of records under each category which are grouped by category for groupby filter i have refered to [AngularJS Group By Directive without External Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992090/angularjs-group-by-directive).

Now i want to limit no of record to be displayed under each category

Output will look like this : There are total 9 records 4 under group 1 and 5 under group 2 
but i want to display 2 records under each category.

```
Group 1

abc
def

Group 2

ghi
jkl
```

Comment: You could use the limitTo filter. See here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Comment: by applying limitTo:4 filter it shows top 4 elements of one group but i want to show 2 elements of each group.

Comment: Why don't use separate ng-repeat for each group??

Comment: if we use separate ng-repeat for each group then only group name will be displayed if there is no element is under that group