# How to Group by an Index in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the userdata out of my passport implementation and i will show them in the admin panel.

```
$scope.users = [

{
    "id": "1", 
    "local": [
        {"email": "test1@email.de"},
        {"name": "Holger"}
    ]
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "local": [
        {"email": "test2@email.de"},
        {"name": "Robert"}
    ]
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "facebook": [
        {"email": "test3@email.de"},
        {"name": "Robert"}
    ]
}
]
```

How can i group / order the data depending on the index?

For example:

```
local
1 Holger test1@email.de
2 Robert test2@email.de

facebook
3 Robert test3@email.de
```

and how is it possible to list the array in local or facebook undepending of the index.

http://jsfiddle.net/D9MAB/2/

Comment: Check this out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992090/angularjs-group-by-directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT (added display of name and email):

http://jsfiddle.net/D9MAB/4/

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="projects"> 
Local
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(index, user) in users | filter:{local:''}">
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="(index, detail) in user.local">{{detail.name}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="(index, detail) in user.local">{{detail.email}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
Facebook
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(index, user) in users | filter:{facebook:''}">
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="(index, detail) in user.facebook">{{detail.name}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="(index, detail) in user.facebook">{{detail.email}}</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: thank you! how would you display the name and the email in the table?

Comment: Here it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/D9MAB/4/. If this is ok for you, can you accept the answer then? Thanks!

Comment: why something like this does'nt work:  <span ng-repeat="(index,detail) in user.local"><td>{{detail.name}}</td><td>{{detail.email}}</td</span>