# List items by type in AngularJs using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some items, lets say they are Cars.  I am using ng repeat to list them.
Cars also have tires.  Let's say I want to list all of the tire options, but there are a several different types of tires, so we want to separate them by their type {summer, road, racing, etc....):

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="individualCar in allCars" ng-show="CarTypeFilter[individualCar.type]">
  <div class="">
    {{individualCar.name}}
  </div>
  <ul>
    <!-- This is the list of all one type of tires --> 
    <li class="TireType1" ng-repeat="tire in individualCar.tires" ng-show="CarTireFilter[tire.type]">
        {{tire.name}}
    </li>
    <!-- This is another list of all another type of tires --> 
    <li class="TireType2" ng-repeat="tire in individualCar.tires" ng-show="CarTireFilter[tire.type]">
        {{tire.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This isn't quite working, since there isn't a separate list of tire types per Car on the Controller $scope, and Im not sure if I need to build one to reference.   How do I filter or list the types of tires separately using `ng-repeat`?
I plan on styling them differently, hence the distinction needed.

Example JSON:

```
{
  "jokes":[
    {
      "id:":1,
      "name":"Tesla",
      "type":"CAR",
      "Tires":[
        {
          "id":1,
          "type": "summer",
          "name":"Goodyear"
        },
        {
          "id":2,
          "type": "summer",
          "name":"Kuhmo"
        },
        {
          "id":3,
          "type": "winter",
          "name":"Perelli"
        },
        {
          "id":4,
          "type": "racing",
          "name":"Cooper"
        }
      ]
    },
    {...}
  ]
}
```

In the controller, I have an associative array that stores the different types {summer, racing, etc) as the key, and a boolean value, so that when they want to see each option via a checkbox, the items show in the ng-repeat:

```
 $scope.CarTireFilter = {"summer":true, "racing":false, ... };
```

Comment: does this cover what you need to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992090/angularjs-group-by-directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to only show items in the list by some specific atrribute then a filter is what you need. See the docs for [Filter & OrderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter).

Do not us ng-show rather use this:

```
div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="individualCar in allCars| 
                                filter: SET CONDITIONS HERE |
                                orderBy: SET CONDITIONS HERE">
```

The other thing I would like suggest is that if you are going to be adding styling based on the various types. You might want to look into doing this in a more angular way using ng-style. Look at the docs [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle). This approach would allow you add the needed styles based on type and not necessarily need to have separate li tags with different classes. you should try and let angular handle this.