# AngularJS change variable form view on ng-if

Tags: angularjs, rest

Ok, so I have a basic variable.

```
$scope.categoryHeader = "";
```

I'm trying to group lists by their category. How do I update the variable from the view? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
<div ng-app="SharePointAngApp" class="row" style="color:white">
  <div ng-controller="spCustomerController">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div ng-if="item.Category.Title != categoryHeader" ng-change="categoryHeader = item.Category.Title">
        <h4>{{item.Category.Title}}</h4>
      </div> 
      <li>
        <a href="{{item.File.ServerRelativeUrl}}">{{item.Title}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Example

#### Category1

- item1
- item2

  #### Category2
- item3

#### **Edit*

*The solution provided below is the best and simplest solution to my question. The other post's solution did not work within the confines of my page.*

Comment: `ng-change` doesn't make sense on a `div` element, since it is designed to monitor for a change to an HTML `input` element, and a `div` is not an `input`.

Comment: anyway, this has already been discussed at length here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992090/angularjs-group-by-directive-without-external-dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call a function on `ng-if`, so that i can persist the value too in my scope variable too based on my condition. you could persist your `$cope.categoryHeader` when it returns false.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='ctrl'>
<div ng-repeat=" item in num"> 
    <div ng-if="display(item)" >  
        display this
    </div>
</div>
</div>

angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.num = [1,2,3];
    $scope.display = function(x) {
        if (x === 2) {  
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
});
```

A sample fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/63raz38t/1/