# Angular group by and filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am trying to group my collection based on a property and at the same time i would like to filter my collection with one property.

When i try the following,

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="(group,parameter) in parameters | filter : { 'type' : '!GroupType' }| groupBy :'group'">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>{{group}}</legend>
                            <div data-ng-repeat="par in parameter">
                                <myfield ng-model="par.value" parameter="par" entry-map="entryMap"></myfield>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
```

I get a lot of errors on the console as follows,

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:
```

I dont have any watch on my collection. What is the correct way to do this.

Comment: I'm almost positive that the problem has to do with the implementation of the 'groupBy' filter, could you please share that code? Thanks!

Comment: I didnt implement the group by on my own, I am using the angular module from here https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Comment: Sorry that it took me so long to answer you, please have a look at my answer and let me know what your thoughts are. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you against using that implementation of the 'groupBy' `$filter`, use [this one instead](https://github.com/josepot/angular-sbrpr-components/tree/master/src/filters/groupBy):

```
angular.module("sbrpr.filters", [])
.filter('groupBy', function () {
  var results={};
    return function (data, key) {
        if (!(data && key)) return;
        var result;
        if(!this.$id){
            result={};
        }else{
            var scopeId = this.$id;
            if(!results[scopeId]){
                results[scopeId]={};
                this.$on("$destroy", function() {
                    delete results[scopeId];
                });
            }
            result = results[scopeId];
        }

        for(var groupKey in result)
          result[groupKey].splice(0,result[groupKey].length);

        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            if (!result[data[i][key]])
                result[data[i][key]]=[];
            result[data[i][key]].push(data[i]);
        }

        var keys = Object.keys(result);
        for(var k=0; k<keys.length; k++){
          if(result[keys[k]].length===0)
            delete result[keys[k]];
        }
        return result;
    };
});
```

Also, [have a look at this post](http://sobrepere.com/blog/2014/10/14/creating-groupby-filter-angularjs/), where I discuss why the implementation that you are using is actually pretty bad.

And finally, please [support my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter/26458093#26458093). Thanks!

Comment: works for me. Thanks for the link, it explained the whole thing clearly.