# Angularjs ng-repeat populate a table to display in certain order

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have three levels of Individuals in my ng-repeat scope, who are to be ordered by their level. Always   the level 1 individuals should be first  then level 2 individuals and then level 3. when there are multiple individuals in the same level, they need to be ordered by their date of birth.

Please help me with the way I can filter this.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called grouping.

If you google 'angular group by filter', you'll come up with this answer (among others): [How can I group data with an Angular filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter), the solution for which works very well.