# NgRepeat, group by multiple dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have the following collection:

```
[
 {
  "_id": "54efdd4a70726f7af1030000",
  "sequence_name": "Do Stuff",
  "calendar": [
   "2015-02-28T09:00:00.000Z",
   "2015-02-28T18:00:00.000Z",
   "2015-03-01T03:00:00.000Z"
  ]
 }
]
```

I need to group it like this:

```
{
 "2015-02-28T09:00:00.000Z": [
  {
   "_id": "54efdd4a70726f7af1030000",
   "sequence_name": "Do Stuff",
  }
 ],
 "2015-02-28T18:00:00.000Z": [
  {
   "_id": "54efdd4a70726f7af1030000",
   "sequence_name": "Do Stuff"
  }
  ]
  // key/values keep going for each ...
}
```

So that I could (hopefully) display the data like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='(date, scheds) in prettyDates'>
    <h6>{{ date | date: 'd MMM'  }}</h6>
    <div>{{ date | date: 'hh:mma' }}</div>
  <div ng-repeat='s in scheds'>
    <div class='event-time'>{{ s.start_time | date: 'h a' }}</div>
    <div class='event-title'>{{ s.sequence_name }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does angular have a way of doing a groupBy when there are multiple items to group by or when groups will have duplicate entries?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter

Comment: The user in that question is not grouping by a collection of dates. They are grouping by only one possible value. What I am trying to do is group by a collection of values, not a single attribute. That answer does not help me in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that angularJs comes with anything like that. An option would be to use lodash or a similar library to do the grouping in your controller and then just loop over the results.

Check this documentation for groupBy in lodash:
https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy