# Based on angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have array called favouriteProducts=[deptName="",item:object(it contains product info like pid,name,brand)] for example

```
favouriteProducts[0]=deptName:"Fresh food"
                 item:object 
                    productid:4356178
                    brand:brand_name

favouriteProducts[3]=deptName:"drinks"
                 item:object 
                    productid:4356110
                    brand:brand_name
favouriteProducts[4]=deptName:"drinks"
                 item:object 
                    productid:4356111
                    brand:brand_name
```

when i display the result the ouput is like (using ng-repeat in html)

```
fresh food
  productid:4356178
fresh food
 productid:4356179
drinks
 productid:43561710
drinks
 productid:43561711
```

But i want output in this way

```
fresh food
 productid:4356178
 productid:4356179
drinks
 productid:43561710
 productid:43561711
```

can anyone suggest me how to do this??
  I want an array like
favouriteProducts[0]=deptName:"Fresh food"
                     item:object 
                    0-->
                        productid:4356178
                        brand:brand_name
                   1-->productid:4356179
                        brand:brand_name
like this it should appear.
department name and respective products

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular ng-repeat conditional wrap items in element (group items in ng-repeat)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493063/angular-ng-repeat-conditional-wrap-items-in-element-group-items-in-ng-repeat)

Comment: check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388763/grouping-objects-with-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can add the items to the array in the following manner:

```
favouriteProducts[0]={deptName:"Fresh food", item: {productid:4356178,brand:brand_name};

favouriteProducts[3]={deptName:"drinks",item:{productid:4356110,brand:brand_name};
favouriteProducts[4]={deptName:"drinks", item:{productid:4356111,brand:brand_name}
```

Then just use ng-repeat  in two div tags.

```
<div ng-repeat="dept in favouriteProducts.deptName">
<h3>{{dept}}</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="item in dept.item">
    {{item.productid}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the task in two ways.

**Option 1**
Use looping and collect all deptNames items under one criteria.

**Options 2**
Use [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby). A wonderful plugin and and a gift to angular developers.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/ywdgs5yg/2/)

```
<h1>Option 1</h1>
<ul ng-repeat="product in newProducts"> {{product.key}}
    <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in product.items">{{value.productid}}</li>
</ul>

<h1>Option 2</h1>
    <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in products |groupBy:'deptName'">     {{key}}
        <li ng-repeat="(akey,avalue) in value">{{avalue.item.productid}}</li>
    </ul>
```