# Organize objects by day

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a blog that displays every post made on a single day in a single div. It's broken down by Day 1, Day 2, etc. Each post is pulled in by an API and each has a posted object, like so:

```
posted : "January 27, 2016"
```

Currently I'm looking through the entire API and displaying them on the page using ng-repeat. I know I can use the date filter method to order them (although the API already has them in the correct order), but how would I make it so it displays a varying number of posts in each day based on their posted date?

```
<div ng-repeat="article in article.items">
  <div class="col-sm-12 day-block">
     {{ article.title }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Ideally I want it to loop through the items, order them by their date, and then display all of the posts that match that date in one block, and then all posts that match another in a second.

Not quite sure how to approach this, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-repeat groupBy date field per day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508068/ng-repeat-groupby-date-field-per-day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
<!--ng-repeat-->
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in article.items | groupBy:'posted_date|date: MMM:dd' | toArray:true ">

    <!-- Date -->
    <span class="date-header">
        {{value[0].posted_date|date:"EEEE, MMM:dd"}}
    </span>
    <!--ng-repeat-->
    <div ng-repeat="article in value | orderBy:'posted_date'">
        {{article}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it