# Manipulating data in angularjs/javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, grouping

I have a an array of objects like this in angular:

```
$scope.data = [
    {name:"John", group:"a"},
    {name:"David", group:"a"},
    {name:"Tom", group:"b"},
];
```

I want to present this data as something like this (in a template):

```
<h2>group a</h2>
John<br/>
David<br/>

<h2>groub b</h2>
Tom<br>
```

How would you suggest to do this? How can I go from the structure at the beginning to the structure at the end?

Comment: I think group b should be Tom instead David in the sample

Comment: use a filter, like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `grouby` filter that would do group for you on basis of `group` property

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | groupBy: 'group'">
  <h1>group {{ key }}</h1> 
  <div ng-repeat="person in value">
    {{ person.name }} 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be sure to install https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter because groupBy requires it.