# How to Group ng-repeat subdocuments?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using AngularJS, where i have SubDocuments and my JSON comes like below. I would like to know how do i group my subdocuments(list inside `orderfood`). my [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/9iB6N3dzMkj79lRgSSPK?p=preview). the result i am getting now is.

```
Isnain Meals

Chicken Burger

Chicken Burger
```

but i would like my result like this

```
Isnain Meals

Chicken Burger(2)
```

The JSON data

```
$scope.lists = [
{
  "_id": "56b0c315e179bb0e00a44dbf",
  "orderfood": [
    {
      "_id": "569d865bff1fe20e00f8ba97",
      "qty": "1",
      "confirm": true,
      "price": 154,
      "name": "Isnain Meals"
    }
  ],
  "content": "9176649143",
  "created": "2016-02-02T14:54:13.926Z"
},
{
  "_id": "56b06ed25b53250e00ccbd73",
  "orderfood": [
    {
      "_id": "569d84f04834c10e003dff36",
      "qty": "1",
      "confirm": true,
      "price": 125,
      "name": "Chicken Burger"
    }
  ],
  "content": "6886058585",
  "created": "2016-02-02T08:54:42.986Z"
},
{
  "_id": "56b06ed25b53250e00ccbd74",
  "orderfood": [
    {
      "_id": "569d84f04834c10e003dff37",
      "qty": "1",
      "confirm": true,
      "price": 125,
      "name": "Chicken Burger"
    }
  ],
  "content": "6886058585",
  "created": "2016-02-02T08:54:42.986Z"
}];
```

my [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/9iB6N3dzMkj79lRgSSPK?p=preview)

Comment: need to map the data in service or controller before passing to view

Comment: tried to separate it, it did not work.. [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/tVwV7hmVtZzEVYDKdMc6?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used lodash to group the subdocuments

```
$scope.groupedByFoodName = _.chain($scope.lists).map(function(each) {
  return each.orderfood
}).flatten().groupBy(function(each) {
  return each.name
}).value();
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/19rnfcra/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter "groupBy"

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in lists | groupBy: 'name'">
   {{key}} ({{value.length}})
</div>
```

value is the list of grouped data.

see related question:
[How can I group data with an Angular filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter)