# Sort multidimensional JSON in angular

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

I get JSON from a database and its structure is like this:

```
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "1",
      "description": "hello"
      }
   ]
```

`description` and `category` are all dynamic, so I can have 5 objects with `category:1` and 2 with `category:3` etc. Or I could have 3 objects with `category:20` and 25 objects with `category:8`.

I want to create HTML elements like this:

```
Category 1
....
....
....

Category 3
....
....
```

I can create a string like this:

```
$scope.hello = [];
angular.forEach(data.data, function(value, key) {
  $scope.hello.push(value.category+" "+value.description)
}
```

so that it will output:

```
Category 1 hello
Category 1 hi
Category 1 bye
Category 3 sup
Category 3 yo
```

But how will I turn this to:

```
Category 1
hello 
hi
bye

Category 3
sup
yo
```

Comment: You should try the grouping of record on server side, I mean from where you are getting the JSON array. And here on the client side just loop and display. That's the best practise and also optimised way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use groupBy of angular.filter module for more info see this answer . [How can I group data with an Angular filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter)

```js
var app = angular.module("app",['angular.filter'])
app.controller('ctrl',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.data = [
                {
                  "category": "1",
                  "description": "hello"
                },
          {
                  "category": "1",
                  "description": "hi"
                },
          {
                  "category": "3",
                  "description": "hai"
                },
          {
                  "category": "1",
                  "description": "hello"
                },
          {
                  "category": "3",
                  "description": "hello"
                },
          {
                  "category": "1",
                  "description": "hai"
                }
   ]
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class="item item-checkbox">
   <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | groupBy: 'category'">
      category: {{ key }}
      <li ng-repeat="d in value |orderBy:'description'">
          {{ d.description }} 
      </li>
   </ul>      
</div>
```

Comment: Wait, do I have to get the filter module like so `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-filter.js"></script>` and then pass this in my app like `var app = angular.module("app",['angular.filter'])` ?

Comment: yes. you must inject angular-filter.js after angular lib. please if this answer help you accept it. thanks

Comment: Sorry , I cannot install the filter for the `groupBy` to work .How did you installed it, so I can make it work? Thanks

Comment: how use it? download it and put in directory.

Answer (score 1):

javascript provides a [sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) function.  In this function I am sorting an array of site objects by two properties; name and region.

```
    function sort(col, direction) {
        switch (col) {
            case "region":
            {
                sites.sort(function(s1, s2) {
                    var r = 0;
                    if (s1.region < s2.region)
                        r = -1;
                    else if (s1.region > s2.region)
                        r = 1;
                    else {
                        if (s1.name < s2.name)
                            r = -1;
                        else if (s1.name > s2.name)
                            r = 1;
                    }
                    return r;
                });
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                sites.sort(function(s1, s2) {
                    var r = 0;
                    if (s1.name < s2.name)
                        r = -1;
                    else if (s1.name > s2.name)
                        r = 1;
                    else {
                        if (s1.region < s2.region)
                            r = -1;
                        else if (s1.region > s2.region)
                            r = 1;
                    }
                    return r;
                });
            }
        }
        if (direction === "desc") {
            this.sites.reverse();
        }
    }
```