# Can I group by multiple fields using Angular-Filter?

Tags: angularjs, group-by, angular-filters

I'm using [Angular-Filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)'s [groupBy](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby) filter.

**Example from GitHub**:

```
$scope.players = [
  {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'},
  {name: 'George', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma'},
  {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma'}
];

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'">
    Group name: {{ key }}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="player in value">
        player: {{ player.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So, the example groups the players collection by **team**. Imagine there's an **age** property for every player object:

```
$scope.players = [
  {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha', age: 19},
  {name: 'George', team: 'beta', age: 19},
  {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma', age: 23},
  {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta', age: 23},
  {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma', age: 23}
];
```

I want to group by **team** and **age**. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried just adding another groupBy?

Comment: What are expected results? What have you tried? Seems like a nested `groupBy` would do what you need

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Follow the example of multiple fields

```js
angular.module('app',['angular.filter'])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) { 
    $scope.players = [
      {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha', age: 19},
      {name: 'George', team: 'beta', age: 19},
      {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma', age: 23},
      {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta', age: 23},
      {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma', age: 23}
    ];
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
  
<meta name="description" content="[groupBy example]"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MainController"> 

<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: '[team,age]'">
  <b>Group name: {{key}}</b>
  <br>
  <li ng-repeat="player in value">
    <b>player:</b> {{ player.name }} 
    <br>
    <b>team:</b> {{player.team}} 
    <br>
    <span ng-if="player.age"><b>age:</b> {{ player.age }}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you access the multiple key's separately in your html?  Key seems to become a string of "team,age" do I need to split that? {{key.team}} is undefined. etc.

Comment: To answer my own comment: `{{value[0].team}}` and `{{value[0].age}}` will do the trick.  With a groupby you should be able to count on at least one row per "team" and "age" (or group) existing, so no need to check `count > 0`.  Far from elegant but it should work and be reliable.  Wish the key would become json or something though when using multiple fields for the key.

Answer (score 3):

try the following i am assuming you want groups to be created using multiple values as criteria

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: '[team,age]'"
```