# How to the group by with 2 columns in Angular filter using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have an array of an object having 3 properties name

1.name
2.team
3.age

http://jsfiddle.net/HpTDj/46/

I want group with both age and team.i done group with team but i have confusion how i need to group with both team and age in my current code.

I need to show the age of the team with the team name. Please suggest what should I do?

**JS:**

```
 $scope.MyList = [
    {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha', age: 19},
      {name: 'George', team: 'beta', age: 19},
      {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma', age: 23},
      {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta', age: 23},
      {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma', age: 23},
      {name: 'Scruath 1', team: 'gamma', age: 22},
      {name: 'Scruath 2', team: 'gamma', age: 22}
                    ];
    $scope.getGroups = function () {
        var groupArray = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.MyList, function (item, idx) {
            if (groupArray.indexOf(item.team) == -1){ groupArray.push(item.team)
            }
        });
        return groupArray.sort();
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div ng-repeat='group in getGroups()'>
             <h2>{{group}}</h2>
              <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in MyList |  groupby:group">{{item.name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: @ Maxim Shoustin : yes but i want solution how to modify my code

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
 <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in MyList | groupBy: '[team,name]'">
 <b>Group name: {{key}}</b>
 <br>
 <li ng-repeat="player in value">
  <b>player:</b> {{ player.name }} 
  <br>
  <b>team:</b> {{player.team}} 
 </li>
</ul>
```

For more details you can [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223686/can-i-group-by-multiple-fields-using-angular-filter)

Comment: Groupby is not working some reason in my application you have idea to archive in my code ??

Comment: you have idea it would be really helpful

Comment: you also want to group by with name?

Comment: im not understand pls guide me where i need to change my code to archive this

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: I want to archive the two column based filter in my code