# Hide repeating element from JSON object in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hello suppose I have a JSON Object

```
`var books = [{
    "Genre": "Sci-fic",
    "Name": "Bookname1"
}, {
    "Genre": "Sci-fic",
    "Name": "Bookname2"
}, {
    "Genre": "Non sci-fic",
    "Name": "Bookname3"
}, {
    "Genre": "Non sci-fic",
    "Name": "Bookname4"
}];`
```

now how I want to show it like

```
               Sci-fic
              Bookname1
              Bookname2
             Non-scific
              Bookname3
              Bookname3
```

I am well aware by angular unique property but unique discard the changes I want to segregate data based on similar string in json object

I have tried so far with unique but no luck. Any suggestion please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I group data with an Angular filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter)

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a filter. 'orderBy' is being provided by angular.js. You can do something like the following to get the expected result :

**INDEX.HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="bookPerGenre in booksToFilter() | filter:filterGenres">
        <b>{{bookPerGenre.Genre}}</b>
        <li ng-repeat="book in books | filter:{Genre: bookPerGenre.Genre}">{{book.Name}}</li>        
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**APP.JS**

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.books = [{
    "Genre": "Sci-fic",
    "Name": "Bookname1"
}, {
    "Genre": "Sci-fic",
    "Name": "Bookname2"
}, {
    "Genre": "Non sci-fic",
    "Name": "Bookname3"
}, {
    "Genre": "Non sci-fic",
    "Name": "Bookname4"
}];

$scope.booksToFilter = function(){
  indexedGenres = [];
  return $scope.books;
};

$scope.filterGenres = function(book) {
        var genreIsNew = indexedGenres.indexOf(book.Genre) == -1;
        if (genreIsNew) {
            indexedGenres.push(book.Genre);
        }
        return genreIsNew;
    };

});
```

You can refer this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uBN3GO85RpojD1x8G4HX?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks but it's not as I wanted it's repeating value  I am looking for result like this
                 Sci-fic
              Bookname1
              Bookname2
               Non-scific
              Bookname3
              Bookname3

Comment: @HimanshuGupta Please look at the updated code(plnkr). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

{{ books[0].Genre }} 
{{ books[0].Name }}

like arrays books[0] used to access the first element.
I hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also need to use `groupBy` filter like the following question

[How can I group data with an Angular filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter)

Something like

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in books | groupBy: 'Genre'">
    {{ key }}
    <li ng-repeat="book in value">
    {{ book.Name }} 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Try it.