# how to group json data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, jsfiddle, angularjs-filter

```
  [{name: 'A', team: 'team alpha', value:"10"},
  {name: 'A', team: 'team beta' value:"20"},
    {name: 'A', team: 'team gamma' value:"40"},
  {name: 'B', team: 'team alpha' value:"15"},
  {name: 'B', team: 'team beta' value:"25"},
  {name: 'C ', team: 'team alpha' value:"30"}];
```

I want to group my dat in such a way that i get the following structure:

```
    name:A
    team alpha: 10
    team beta: 20
    team gamma:40

   name:B
    team alpha:15
    team beta:25

   name:C
   team alpha:30
```

I check online but could not find a way to group this kind of structure. Is there a way I can group or filter the data in angularjs in the above mentioned format. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to get the values according to team names? Did't you try loop and conditions?

Comment: @DinithMinura That would complicate things a lot and does not seem to be a feasible solution.

Answer (score 4):

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/wuzalasove/edit?html,js,output)

**HTML**

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'name'">
  <li>name: {{ key }}
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="player in value">
          {{ player.team }} : {{player.value}} 
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$scope.players = [
      {name: 'A', team: 'team alpha', value:10},
      {name: 'A', team: 'team beta',value:20},
      {name: 'A', team: 'team gamma',value:40},
      {name: 'B', team: 'team alpha',value:15},
      {name: 'B', team: 'team beta',value:25},
      {name: 'C', team: 'team alpha',value:30}
    ];
```

For detail, [have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24879563/3186722).