# Group elements using lodash - group By date

Tags: angular, typescript, group-by

I need to group elements by some properties of the object of an array. I don't want to use custom pipe for that. Is there any way to implement group by.

Sample Array:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "date": "2018-02-01T19:24:05.524+05:30",
      "client":{  
         "id":1
      },
      "process":{  
         "id":1,
         "date":"02-01-2018 11:54:05"
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "date": "2018-02-01T17:35:05.524+05:30",
      "client":{  
         "id":2
      },
      "process":{  
         "id":2,
         "date":"02-01-2018 11:54:05"
      }
   },
]
```

I want to group array by `date`, `client Id` and `process date`.

I am trying to use lodash group-by. For `client Id` It is working fine but for the other dates I want to group elements by date only . I don't want to include time in that. Is there any way to exclude time in group-by?

Hope someone can help

Comment: what is the output object will look like?

Comment: do you need to group the array or just list grouped?
if you want to show it grouped, you can try `angular` `groupBy`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37717769/4730201

Comment: @Aravind In outout object all the elements related to all the clients would be listed together.. like 1 object for client Id 1 and It should display all the records where client ID is 1 same for other client Ids

Comment: @RicardoPontual I dont want to use pipes as I need to process some data in my component

Comment: have a look at the lodash [**groupBy**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy)

Comment: have you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key

Comment: Ok I will try lodash groupBy ..