# Angularjs Sorting data in ng-repeat two items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two jsons: templates, and images

```
$scope.templates = [
        {"id_template": 1, "name": "First Template", "group": "sport"}
        {"id_template": 2, "name": "Second Template", "group": "animals"},
        ];

    $scope.images = [
        {"id_image": 1, "id_template": 1, "title":"Image Lewy"},
        {"id_image": 2, "id_template": 1, "title":"Image ball"},
        {"id_image": 3, "id_template": 2, "title":"Image dog"},
    ]
```

I would like to display in the view images sorted by id_template. I know that you must create a loop in the loop but do not know how ?
My view.html:

```
<div class="images" ng-repeat="template in templates">
 {{template: name}}
 Images to this template: 
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="image in images | filter:template.id_template">{{image.title}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: create a fiddle

Comment: There is an error in your filter, it should look like this `filter:{id_template:template.id_template}` Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e0hfdnad/) for anyone to use

Comment: @George its working i have one more question: in templates i have group and i want show only one group it means: group: 1, group:1, i want show only one group in view and images to this group how to do this?

Comment: <div class="images" ng-repeat="template in templates | filter : {group : 'animals'}"> add this

Comment: it must be universal not to one group

Answer (score 4):

You can sort in angular by using orderBy filter. Please go through https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy documentation if you want more details. From example below the result will be ascending and if you want it to be descending order add '-template_id'

**Ascending**

```
<div class="images" ng-repeat="template in templates | orderBy: 'template_id'">
 {{template.name}}
 Images to this template: 
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="image in images | filter:{id_template:template.id_template}">{{image.title}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Descending**

```
<div class="images" ng-repeat="template in templates | orderBy: '-template_id'">
 {{template.name}}
 Images to this template: 
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="image in images | filter:{id_template:template.id_template}">{{image.title}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i have one more question: in templates i have group and i want show only one group it means: group: 1, group:1, i want show only one group in view and images to this group how to do this?

Comment: You can use ng-if to filter the group

Comment: it means  how to use ng-if

Comment: Do you mean that you want the result of group1 only or grouping by record?

Comment: grouping by record

Comment: You can refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter)

Answer (score 1):

your almost there but have a small syntax error which is you need to print like `{{template.name}}` instead of `{{template: name}}`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="images" ng-repeat="template in templates">
 {{template.name}}
 Images to this template: 
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="image in images | filter:{id_template:template.id_template}">{{image.title}}</li>
</ul>
</div
  </body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.templates = [
        {"id_template": 1, "name": "First Template", "group": "sport"},
        {"id_template": 2, "name": "Second Template", "group": "animals"}
        ];

    $scope.images = [
        {"id_image": 1, "id_template": 1, "title":"Image Lewy"},
        {"id_image": 2, "id_template": 1, "title":"Image ball"},
        {"id_image": 3, "id_template": 2, "title":"Image dog"},
    ]
  
 
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use OrderBy for sorting items in angularjs

```
<li ng-repeat="image in images | orderBy:template.id_template">{{image.title}}</li>
```