# How to import a npm module in Angular Application?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I came across this npm package which groups array according to our requirement.
I need to use this package in my angular application to group my array.
How should I import these package to my angular application.
Is there are any other module present to group array.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/group-array#examples

Comment: did you find any of these answers helpful?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247333/group-an-array-of-objects-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You should use import it using ES6 syntax example:

```
import groupArray from 'group-array';
```

Here is [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rl1w4d)

This is exactly the syntax used to import angular modules

Answer (score 0):

import { Observable} from 'rxjs'

as type follow syntex of ES6 import will work here

Answer (score 0):

If you are using typescript then

```
  import * as ga from "../../../../../node_modules/group-array"; //proper path to your node_modules/group-array

  arr = [
    {tag: 'one', content: 'A'},
    {tag: 'one', content: 'B'},
    {tag: 'two', content: 'C'},
    {tag: 'two', content: 'D'},
    {tag: 'three', content: 'E'},
    {tag: 'three', content: 'F'}
  ];  

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(ga(this.arr, 'tag'));
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you plz try this once,
install it first using npm

```
npm install group-array

import * as groupArray from 'group-array'
```