# Angular 1.6 - ng-repeat orderby and groupby items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So what I want to achieve is:

- loop through array of messages **(ng-repeat)**
- sort messages by date
- then group current message with previous one, if author is matching **(store in the same div element)**
- create new div if current messages's author is not matching previous one
- continue loop

I'm stuck here:

```
<div class="message" ng-repeat="msg in chatDetails.msgList">
  <p>{{ msg.text }}</p>
</div>
```

I need to keep exact order - simply, if previous element doesn't match with current - new box should be created.

Is that even possible in angular? If so, could you show me how, please?

Thank you!

## edit

Heres sample result of `chatDetails`:

```
  {
    msgList: [
      { author: 0, text: 'hi', date: 1493050181799 },
      { author: 1, text: 'hola!', date: 1493050181801 },
      { author: 1, text: 'wilkomen', date: 1493050181802 },
      { author: 0, text: 'czesc', date: 1493050181803 }
      { author: 0, text: 'ciao', date: 1493050181804 }
      { author: 1, text: 'bonjour', date: 1493050181805 }
    ]
  }
```

Somehow desired result:

```
<div class="message-list">
  <div class="message-group" data-author="1">
    <div class="message">
      <p>hola</p>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <p>ciao</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-group" data-author="0">
    <div class="message">
      <p>hola</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message-group" data-author="1">
    <div class="message">
      <p>hola</p>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <p>hola</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you passing `chatDetails` to the controller?
you can check by adding the following html `<pre><code>{{ chatDetails }} </code></pre>` (do it above the message)

Comment: @DenisTsoi `chatDetails` is scope variable. Created by directive in this case.

Comment: ah sorry - i didn't read the whole message - so you're just to solve the `group by` section of the problem. Maybe `groupBy` filter may help.

Comment: i'd need more info on `chatdetails` structure before i can continue ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter)

Comment: @DenisTsoi of course. Sorry about it. I've edited my post

Comment: JSFiddle working example - https://jsfiddle.net/plantface/L6cQN/

Comment: Or just google - **ng-repeat group by example in jsfiddle**. You found many solution.

Comment: @Utkarsh Dubey no. Those are completely different cases. Example you guys redirected me to, groups all items into 1 box. I need to keep the order, and create the same wrapper-div multiple times (if there's such need). Please, take a look at desired output i posted in edit.

Comment: `orderby: 'date' | groupBy: 'author'` -

Comment: @DenisTsoi, completely agree. Reference link - https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/issues/57#issuecomment-65041792

Comment: @DenisTsoi again: no. This **does not** do what I described above. What it does, it creates just **2 divs**, in which it outputs all messeges, according to sender's id. What's the point of doing such chat? I need all messages to be  displayed in valid order.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey I wish, but that's not doing the job.

Comment: I finished my job for today, I'll be back once i got home. Thank you for your help, guys.

Comment: @PatrykCieszkowski dude - idk what that response was about - kinda crappy attitude if people are freely assisting - chill

Comment: @DenisTsoi you shall chill, buddy, as I just told you. The example shown is completely not related to the question. I even thanked you for your time, and now you jump on me. Grab a beer and calm down.

Comment: the example i gave above was helped along by Utkarsh (which is in the right direction) - the issue is- idk why youre taking it out one someone  (it's not like i'm bugging you - besides - you're taking it out on someone who's only commented partially, and is pointing to the right direction)

(`ordering by date then grouping by author is what you asked for`) - the specifics i've yet to finalise but it kinda sucks getting the brunt of that negativity when i've just spent an hour reasearching for you.

Comment: @DenisTsoi because I can not mention two users at once. That's why. And because you reported a duplicate - which redirects to same example dear Utkarsh shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate doesn't mean it is. It's nothing personal.

Comment: @DenisTsoi and no. The output is clearly not what I needed. If you're kind enough, please take a look at my post again, I updated earlier desired output there - that's what I'd like to achieve. But instead, ordering by date and then grouping by author - gives just 2 divs, to which it prints all the data. Sure it isn't. You just were the first one. :)

Comment: Look my comment of the pipe doesn't solve your problem since it requires a custom filter - which i was looking at before being mentioned (obvious since there isn't an answer below) - that's because the `angular-filter` that Utkarsh has linked (a library of reusable filters) has encountered this problem. Aka - this is not a trivial problem. Good luck anyway

Answer (score -1):

I believe your problem can be solved with "orderBy".

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

It would look something like:

```
<div class="message" ng-repeat="msg in chatDetails.msgList | orderBy: 'date'">
    <p>{{ msg.text }}</p>
</div>
```

If your msg objects have some date or index value, you can sort by that number.

Comment: Hi. That would just solve the order, but wouldnt help with grouping. But thank you anyways!