# AngularJS: GroupBy and show items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I've got an application where I retreive the information of some objects (into an array). That array would have the following structure:

```
$scope.items = [    
    {
        id: 23289323,
        event: {
            id: 972823,
            name: 'Event A name',
            datetime: '2017-02-01 13:45',
        },
        player: {
            id: 58392,
            name: 'Player A name'
        },
        team: {
            id: 38839,
            name: 'Team A'
        },
        datetime: '2017-02-03 22:23'
    },
    {
        id: 482273784,
        event: {
            id: 972823,
            name: 'Event A name',
            datetime: '2017-02-01 13:45',
        },
        player: {
            id: 2989273,
            name: 'Player B name'
        },
        team: {
            id: 2323434,
            name: 'Team B'
        },
        datetime: '2017-02-03 22:23'
    },
    {
        id: 283273939,
        event: {
            id: 23092803,
            name: 'Event B name',
            datetime: '2017-02-01 13:45',
        },
        player: {
            id: 58392,
            name: 'Player A name'
        },
        team: {
            id: 38839,
            name: 'Team A'
        },
        datetime: '2017-02-03 22:23'
    }
    ...
]
```

### What I'd like

I'd like to be able to have two lists.

On the left, a list of some customizable groupingBy AngularJS filter. So, I can specify "group it by player" and it shows, on this left list, a list of the players with some information (for example, showing the player's name).

On the right, when I select a specific player, show the items that have this player associated.

### What I've tried

```
<li data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in Ctrl.items | groupBy: 'event.id'">
{{key}}<br/>{{value}}
</li>
```

### What I get

```
23289323
{id: 23289323,event: {id: 972823,name: 'Event name',datetime: '2017-02-01 13:45',}, player: {id: 58392, name: 'Player name'}, team: { id: 38839,name: 'Team A'}, datetime: '2017-02-03 22:23'}
```

So, I'm getting the whole `item` object, but I've not found any way of getting the item that I'm `groupBy`ing. Because, right now, if there are 3 items with that `event.id` I get three `<li></li>` in stead of only one (the one of the `event` object).

### What I ask

Is there any way of using AngularJS `groupBy` filter and getting in return the (whole) object that is specifying the grouping?

*Remember that the `groupBy` key can be changed by the user.*

If you need any further information, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you also post the code for the `groupBy` filter?

Comment: It's not a filter made by me, but included in angular.filter module. You can see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter (and I think there is the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/drubarth/R8YZh/). Thank you!

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but `groupBy` relies heavily on your data structure, which right now is just an object with no similar values to group or differentiate from. Can you expand on what `Ctrl.items` is? Should have more data to work with... (more events, etc)

Comment: Done! Question updated. As you can see, all the objects have the same fields, the only that changes is the properties of the subobjects like `event`, `player`, and so on. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've made it through a custom filter. I'm not sure if it's the best way, so **if anyone has another solution, please post it!**

This is the **code of the filter**:

```
(function(){
    angular.module("AppModule").filter('groupByGrouped', function() {
        return function(list, groupedElement) {
            var result = [];
            var used_elements = [];
            var ref_item;
            var ref_check;

            // Loop through every list item
            angular.forEach(list, function(item){
                // We take the object we want to group by inside the item 
                ref_item = item[groupedElement];

                // If it exists
                if(ref_item !== undefined){
                    if(ref_item.id !== undefined){
                        // If it has an ID, we take the ID to make it faster. 
                        ref_check = ref_item.id;
                    }else{
                        // Otherwise, we identify the specific object by JSON string (slower method)
                        ref_check = JSON.stringify(ref_item);
                    } 

                    // If it does not exist yet
                    if(used_elements.indexOf(ref_check) == -1){
                        // We add it to the results
                        result.push(ref_item);
                        // And we add it to the already used elements so we don't add it twice
                        used_elements.push(ref_check);
                    }
                }else{
                    // Otherwise we log it into our console
                    console.warn("The key '"+groupedElement+"' inside the specified item in this list, does not exist.");
                }
            });

            return result;
        };
    });
})();
```

This will return the whole object. So **our HTML** would be something like:

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="(key, obj) in Ctrl.items | groupByGrouped: 'event'">
        <span class="object_id">{{obj.id}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or even **with a directive** (not tested, but should work aswell):

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="(key, obj) in Ctrl.items | groupByGrouped: 'event'">
        <obj_directive ourobject="obj"></obj_directive>
    </li>
</ul>
```