# Angular ng-repeat sort into several divs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a some code that currently displays all my items and sort them by icon.

```
  <li ng-repeat="availableItem in model.availableItems | compareArrays:model.selectedItems:'alias' | orderBy:'icon' | filter:searchTerm"
            ng-click="selectItem(availableItem)"
            class="-three-in-row">            
            <a class="umb-card-grid-item" href="" title="{{ availableItem.name }}">
                <i class="{{ availableItem.icon }}"></i>
                {{ availableItem.name }}
           </a>
   </li>
```

My goal is to create a div for each icon type (categories) and place them inside the div how can I do that in angular? I have tried with ng-if but cant get it to work the way I want to. Desired output would look something like this [image]

Comment: would you please explain more of what you want to do? (E.g: give us your desired HTML output)

Comment: I think you need a [`groupBy` filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter), from `angular.filter` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groupBy filter and apply css accordingly to each li tag.

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in stuff | groupBy: 'category'">
    category name: {{ key }}
      <li ng-repeat="item in value">
        item: {{ item.name }} 
      </li>
</ul>
```

Also https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter is a great resource as well that allows you to do more outside AngularJs box.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:
[How can I group data with an Angular filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter)

All you need to do is to substitute the key with the div for your icon group.