# Expandable ng-repeat from Json AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to do collapsing `<ul></ul>` - after click `age` i want to collapse under `name` and then the deeper json structure. Now i am in that moment :

```
 <div ng-repeat="key in messages">
  <ul ng-repeat=" (x, y) in key">
   <li>{{y.age}}</li>
  <li style="margin-left:15px;" ng-repeat="(a,b) in y.names" >{{b.name}}</li>
  <ul style="margin-left:35px;" ng-repeat="p in a.full_name" >
       <li>{{p}}</li>
          </ul>
          </ul>
  </div>
```

My plunker : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/902dF10onLRdAvo3gRBa?p=preview

I don't know how to get `full_names` from json.
Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: your `ng-repeat` with `(a,b)` was closed too early, so the second `ng-repeat` with `a.full_name` doesn't have a reference to `a`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Yeah, thank you. Have you maybe idea for collapse this json? You know after click y.age toggle the b.name

Comment: your JSON makes very little sense. I think it's better to structure it differently - per _user_, with some properties like name, age, full_name, etc. Then you can [`groupBy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24879563/8495123) it in `ng-repeat`