# Group array of objects in Angular Material with *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, loops, group-by

Similar to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter), **I want to group an array of objects**, `e.g., by team name`

```
[
 {name: 'Gene', team: 'team alpha'},
 {name: 'George', team: 'team beta'},
 {name: 'Steve', team: 'team gamma'},
 {name: 'Paula', team: 'team beta'},
 {name: 'Scruath of the 5th sector', team: 'team gamma'}
];
```

Unfortunately, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24879563/2745116) using `ng-repeat` with a `groupBy` filter doesn't seem to work within an Angular Material expansion panel, which is what I'm trying to do:
I want multiple expansion panels, one per team, which, when expanded, show the involved players.

I tried

```
<mat-expansion-panel ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>{{ key }}</mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <li ng-repeat="player in value">
      {{player.name}}
    </li>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

However, `ng-repeat`is not allowed inside the `mat-expansion-panel`. `*ngFor` is allowed but I don't know how to use it with the `groupBy` filter. `*ngFor="let player in players | groupBy: 'team'"` throws an error and I can't find any documentation.

Comment: You can use [`lodash.groupby`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make your own **`custom pipe`** to support GroupBy, also ng-repeat is an angularjs syntax, you should use **`ngFor`**.

Your custom pipe should look as,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'groupBy'})
export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(collection: Array<any>, property: string): Array<any> {
         if(!collection) {
            return null;
        }

        const groupedCollection = collection.reduce((previous, current)=> {
            if(!previous[current[property]]) {
                previous[current[property]] = [current];
            } else {
                previous[current[property]].push(current);
            }

            return previous;
        }, {});

        return Object.keys(groupedCollection).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedCollection[key] }));
    }
}
```

[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bs4e7g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgroup.pipe.ts)

Comment: Why would they remove functionality from AngularJS? I'd expect many people could benefit from a built-in "groupBy" pipe.

Comment: Follow up question: What if I'm trying to group by date, but not exact date (with time) only really year, month, day? I tried chaining pipes but it didn't work. I would probably have to drop the hour, minute, second, millisecond before, right?