# AngularJS - ng-repeat list is not working using groupby filter , when a model element is added from the model array

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS - ng-repeat list is not working using groupby filter , when a model element is added from the model array

```
angular.module('ibeApp').filter('groupBy', function () {
return _.memoize(function (items, field)
{
    return _.groupBy(items, field);
}
);});

  <div class="row">
        <div class="list_top1" ng-repeat="(key, value) in book.paxinfo | groupBy: 'RatePlanName'">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <ng-form name="guestform">
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 pad_left0">
                        <div class="row room_bg">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 pad_bot">
                                <div class="room_name">
                                    {{$index+1}}. {{key}}
                                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you share how the data look like, the data in "book" scope variable. That will help us identify the issue.

Comment: In above json, we are going to add the muliple values in paxinfo array, it is not showing ng-group using groupby.

Comment: your json seems to be invalid.

Comment: {"contactinfo":{"HotelId":"1110","DepositFullAmoutSelection":null},"paxinfo":[{"additionalAdultCount":0,"TempId":1,"RoomTypeID":1,"RatePlanID":111001001,"RoomTypeName":"Executive Room","RatePlanName":"Executive Room","MaxAdult":3,"MaxChild":2,"ChildAge":[],"ChildAgeDisplay":null,"Tax":522,"PromoRate":2900,"AutelRate":2900,"Discount":0,"ExtraAdultRate":0,"ExtraChildRate":0,"RoomAmount":3422,"GuestFname":null,"GuestLname":"","GuestReq":"","SecurityDeposit":0,"TaxNameValue":[{"TaxDesc":"GST","TaxCalType":"%","TaxCharge":18,"TaxAmount":522}]}],"serviceinfo":{"opservice":[],"manservice":[]}}

Comment: pls find the json

Comment: I think you're missing something very subtle, take a look at this sample: http://jsbin.com/weyov/45/edit?html,js,output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter

Comment: but my problem , when i add new value in array, it is not showing in ng-repeat.

Comment: I will recommend you take paxInfo into another scope variable and bind that in your HTML instead of book.paxInfo. Also make sure you have added required dependency in your code, which is required for filter to work (angular.filter or $filter)

Comment: Can share any sampples instead of groupby

Comment: I already shared 2 sample code links in my previous comment above.

Comment: it is not related to newly  added value

Comment: finally i found solution. there are groupby filter

Comment: What is it. I guess something trivial?

Comment: there are some issue in groupby filter only.I changed groupby filter function.