# Why does this grouping angular filter cause a digest loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to display a bunch of items in chunks of N items at a time. I need to chunk the items because the markup has to be tabular / gridded (there's a row for each group of N items, then a column for each item). Here's a simplified attempt:

```
app.filter('inGroupsOf', function () {
    return function (input, groupSize) {
        if (!input) {
            return [];
        }
        var result = [];
        for (var index = 0; index < input.length; index++) {
            var groupIndex = Math.floor(index / groupSize);
            if (!result[groupIndex]) {
                result[groupIndex] = [];
            }
            result[groupIndex].push(input[index]);
        }
        return result;
    };
});

<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="itemGroup in items | inGroupsOf:7">
        <span ng-repeat="item in itemGroup">{{item.name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

(full version here: http://jsfiddle.net/bradleybuda/twhVj/3/ )

This results in a "10 $digest() iterations reached" error. I've looked at the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462015/angular-grouping-filter) but the suggestions there don't work for me (other than nuking the filter and doing this all in the controller). Is there any way to make this kind of ng-repeat work with a template / filter? Doing it in the controller feels ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinite loop is occurring because of line 12 in the controller:

```
result[groupIndex] = [];
```

The $digest loop is not occurring because you are creating an array within a defined loop, but because you are nesting these new arrays within an array that you created in line 8:

```
var result = [];
```

The same error will occur even if you create your nested array outside of your for loop:

```
var result = [];
    result[0] = [];
```

The same thing occurs with nested objects as well.  As to "why" this occurs, I'm not very sure.  I've read over the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest) but still don't really understand why the nesting of arrays or objects causes the $digest looping to occur.  Replace the nested array with a string or a number and you're golden.

I guess in this case, the logic has to move back to the controller, and not be called as a filter.