# Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached! Aborting! during walking through slices of arrays using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

JSbin: http://jsbin.com/oxugef/1/edit

Im trying to slice an array to smaller subarrays and loop through them to create an evenly divided table of divs. If I understood correctly, I'm overwriting some model during loop, which results in unexpected insconsistencies. But I could not find which model is overwritten during loops.

This is an example of what i am trying to achieve:

```
data = {"key1": [1,2,3,4,...] //val1 
        , ...}
divs:
    div.key1
       div1,div2,div3,div4,div5
       div6,div7,...

    div.key2
       div21,div22,div23,div24,div25
       div26,div27,...
    ...
```

It lines up the divs as expected but the "...Aborting" error logs fill up the development console.

What am i doing wrong here, that results in this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this stackoverfolow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507040/angular-filter-works-but-causes-10-digest-iterations-reached), you should make your filter to return the same exact objects since if the object get changed during the repeater, it will cause the error in $digest.

```
.filter("group", function () {
    return _.memoize(function (items, count) {
        var out = [],
            temp = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            temp.push(items[i]);
            if (temp.length == count) {
                out.push(temp);
                temp = [];
            }
        }
        if (temp.length) out.push(temp);
        return out;
    });
});
```

Try it here [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oxugef/3/)

Comment: thank you for directing me to the relevant thread. I wasn't aware that "group" was returning different objects each time, even if the result was the same as before.