# count key value with angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of items that I'm repeating over using ng-repeat and am using group filter

this is my array

```
var items = [
   { product_id : 1, quantity : 2 }
   { product_id : 1, quantity : 3 }
   { product_id : 2, quantity : 2 }
   { product_id : 3, quantity : 4 }
   { product_id : 2, quantity : 8 }
];
```

I would like an ng-repeat that results in the following presentation

```
| product_id 1 | quantity 5 |
| product_id 2 | quantity 10 |
| product_id 3 | quantity 4 |
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why not use something like lodash to preprocess/group the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's old question I saw that I can answer this more clearly.

I'm using [`angular-filter`](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module to get `groupBy` filter.

```js
angular.module('app', ['angular.filter']).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    { product_id : 1, quantity : 2 },
    { product_id : 1, quantity : 3 },
    { product_id : 2, quantity : 2 },
    { product_id : 3, quantity : 4 },
    { product_id : 2, quantity : 8 }
  ];
}).
filter('total', function() {
  return function(arr, prop) {
    return arr.reduce(function(previousValue, currentObj) {
      return previousValue + currentObj[prop];
    }, 0);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | groupBy : 'product_id'">
    | product_id {{key}} | quantity {{value | total: 'quantity'}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

There is a better way to calc the sum of each group thanks, again, to `angular-filter` (and [@toddbranch](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/issues/191#issuecomment-187949849)). To calculate the total you can use `map` and `sum` filter. like this:

```
{{value | map: 'quantity' | sum}}
```

And the full demo:

```js
angular.module('app', ['angular.filter']).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    { product_id : 1, quantity : 2 },
    { product_id : 1, quantity : 3 },
    { product_id : 2, quantity : 2 },
    { product_id : 3, quantity : 4 },
    { product_id : 2, quantity : 8 }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | groupBy : 'product_id'">
    | product_id {{key}} | quantity {{value | map: 'quantity' | sum}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying nesting the ng-repeat tag in the html tags like so,

```
<div ng-repeat 1>
  <div ng-repeat 2>
    <!-- where you need the data -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own filter. Need some work on below filter to get the addition of quantity with same `product_id`.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items | orderBy: 'product_id' |groupBy:'product_id':'quantity'">
   {{i.product_id}}| {{i.quantity}}
</div>
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('groupBy', function() {
    return function(values, property1, property2) {
        var groupByArray = [];
        console.log("Initialize");
        angular.forEach(values, function(value, index) {
            var lengthOfGroupBy = groupByArray.length;
            if (lengthOfGroupBy == 0 || groupByArray[lengthOfGroupBy - 1][property1] != value[property1]) {
                groupByArray.push(value);
            }
        });
        return groupByArray;
    }
});
```

[Working Fiddlle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13208/)

**UPDATE**

I tried further and successfully implement the thing which you want, it works but there is error in console which says `"Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!”`

Here is my [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13211/) with error in console.

I found the [solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507040/angular-filter-works-but-causes-10-digest-iterations-reached?answertab=active#tab-top) that works for same problem.

Comment: Initially the lengthOfGroupBy is 0 so the result of if statement is always false..

Comment: @UlukBiy thats my bad.Thanks for heads up..I pasted wrong code(the one which i was trying for quantity addition).

Comment: @rslhdyt does it helpful to you?