# Angularjs Nested Ng-repeat By Number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a bunch of data I would like to display in a sliding carousel type layout. Ideally we would show 8 of these data points in each slide, so that it would look something like this:

```
Slide
    datapoint 1
    datapoint 2
    datapoint 3
    datapoint 4
    datapoint 5
    datapoint 6
    datapoint 7
Slide
    datapoint 8
    datapoint 9
    datapoint 10
    datapoint 11
    etc etc...
```

Now I know how to iterate over these datapoints using ng-repeat, however, i'm not sure how I can iterate while grouping them into their own respective groups.

Currently i'm using `ng-repeat="(index, master) in data"` to iterate, but obviously, this gives me a list of items without the grouping that i'm after.

Any ideas?

Comment: `limitTo` can be applied to `ng-repeat`, or you may need an `ng-if` and check that the `$index % 8 == 0` for a new slide, or you setup a paging system and keep track of the skip and limit.

Comment: @tymeJV Do you have an example of that? i'm trying with:
 ng-repeat="(index,master) in repeatingData | limitTo:8"

Answer (score 0):

take a look in here.
[angular grouping filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462015/angular-grouping-filter)

There's nice example about grouping. This may be the thing you need.

Edit: wrong link. :)

Comment: Appears that will work for me, but there are some issues with it - $digest bug.