# ng-repeat group by similar dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using AngularJS `ng-repeat` to display a chat view with a history of multiple days. To make the chat easier to read I want to add headers when there is a pause of some hours between two messages. (Like you may know it from mobile messenger apps.)

I know this could be done by grouping them and I'm aware of `groupBy:`. However `groupBy:` only allows to group by some value of the object, but I need to group it by **similar** timestamps. (Like grouping dates together when delay between them is less then one hour.)

Is there a simple way to realize that?

Comment: same post as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493063/angular-ng-repeat-conditional-wrap-items-in-element-group-items-in-ng-repeat

Comment: in the post you linked they are grouping by keys like "alpha", "beta", "gamma" - i don't see the relation to this question where we don't have static keys for sorting

Answer (score -2):

You can use custom filter as groupBy parameters

```
ng-repeat="chat in chats | customFilter:100"
```

CustomFilter as per example in [angular grouping filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462015/angular-grouping-filter)

```
app.filter('customFilter', function(){
return function(items, timing) {
  var groups = [],
     inner;
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     //do timestamp grouping
     {
        inner = [];
        groups.push(inner);
     }
     inner.push(items[i]);
  }
  return groups;
 };
 });
```