# AngularJS + PhoneGap $digest iterations

Tags: cordova, angularjs

I am getting an error with $digest iterations when running my app on phonegap.  On a vanilla web browser, I don't get any errors.  Any help here would be great.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had what appears to be a circular reference.  I had function calls built into the scope that ran a redirect function bound to the ng-click directive.  When i removed these redirect functions from ngclick and instead just called the redirect function implicitly using onclick and removed the pointer function from the scope object, it began working.  I believe it was caused by a function within the scope trying to change the view, thus creating a situation where the watcher never ended because it was still waiting on the view to change and for the view to change the control had to be dereferenced.

Answer (score 3):

This error is usually caused when you have a watcher on some expression (in controller or directive) that modifies the value of that expression, which results in an infinite loop. Please review all your watchers.

[here is an similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277542/10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting-due-to-filter-using-angularjs)